# Reading an image file

Tags: android, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using ContentProviderClient vs ContentResolver to access content provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084896/using-contentproviderclient-vs-contentresolver-to-access-content-provider)

I am trying to read an image file, but I am getting this parameter from the viewer app as my activity is invoked:

```
content://media/external/images/media/5820
```

I tried to read it using a `File` object, but the path is not valid. What is the proper way to get the content of the file in a `byte[]`?

Answer (score 2):

Use below code to open uri

```
ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver();
InputStream is = cr.openInputStream("content://media/external/images/media/5820");
```